# When I set an export PROMPT_COMMAND, it changes my terminal settings?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash

So, I wanted to add a timestamp to my terminal prompt and I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193416/adding-timestamps-to-terminal-prompts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  askUbuntu answer to do so. And it works fine. In my terminal preferences I have set the new tab to open the present working directory. After adding the export PROMPT_COMMAND in .bash_profile, however my new tab opens the default directory. When I comment out that line, it works normally again.

Why does this happen? How can I get timestamps on my terminal prompt without messing up my new tab settings

Comment: By default `PROMPT_COMMAND` calls `update_terminal_cwd` to do a lot of things. You probably need to tie into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is used by the system `bash` to enable per-session history. If you look at `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` you see

```
# Note that this uses PROMPT_COMMAND to enable per-session history
# the first time for each new session. If you customize PROMPT_COMMAND
# be sure to include the previous value. e.g.,
#
#   PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }your_code_here"
```

So if you want to follow the recommendations in the advice you've linked to you are better off just using

```
export PS1="\t [\u@\h \W]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

or similar. If you really want to use `PROMPT_COMMAND`

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }echo -n \[\$(date +%H:%M:%S)\]\ "
```

but the prompt will get messed up if you navigate back in time with <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>.